# Rails Migarations with same Timestamp

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I am working on a rails application which is distributed across 20 people. Somehow two users created migrations with same time stamp, and they pushed their code to the central project management system.Since schema migrations table maintains only versions which are simply time stamps( also primary key of the table) How rails will handle this kind of situation ? Can anyone explain..? What will happen if i wish to remove that entry from schema migration table ? Which migration's time stamp will be removed?

Comment: I will say that will be quite rare for only 20 people :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expect to see the following error when running migrations

```
rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the version number
```

Things get pretty unpleasant when migrations get 'out of sync', which I think is possible with teams.

Another big problem is if users go back and change earlier migrations, naughty!

I blogged about managing migrations when things get out of sync here.

http://www.fmhcc.com.au/ruby/database-migrations-in-rails-and-when-to-start-from-scratch/